# SHOW ALL equivalent for custom settings

Tags: postgresql

Is there equivalent to `show all` or `select * from pg_show_all_settings()` but for custom settings?

If I do this:

```
select * from set_config('myconf.test', 'my_val', false);
```

Then I can read that value with one of those:

```
postgres=# select * from current_setting('myconf.test', true);
 current_setting
-----------------
 my_val
(1 row)

postgres=# show myconf.test;
 myconf.test
-------------
 my_val
(1 row)
```

But it won't show up if I use `show all` or in `pg_show_all_settings()`.

What I'm trying to do is to pass some additional variables to function (or any query), without using regexp or any other type of string substitution, dynamic generation and so on. Just execute query as normal, but pass some additional data to it, not caring if it actually is capable of making use of it or not.

I plan on query side to have generic code that will log those variables that were available in session/transaction. It isn't really crucial to have them all (those that got used will suffice), but it could help with debug to have them.

Comment: For various custom settings I use my own table to store them.